# What does “BC break” mean?

Tags: terminology

I've found on GitHub term “BC break” – what does it mean?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

"BC break" usually means [backward compatibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_compatibility) in a general term, but as David Schwartz said it can be interpreted as *binary compatibility break* in some contexts.

Answer (score 17):

A "BC break" is a binary compatibility break. Nokia documents it pretty well in the [compatibility overview](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Compatibility_Overview#Binary_compatibility_.28BC.29_break). Basically it means that code developed with earlier versions of a compiler, library, or operating system won't work on devices or run times built using a newer version.